# The best way to store data on client web side about user

Tags: javascript, html, security, web

I want to implement next features:

1. I want to greet user by his login name on my webpage (like 'Hello, Fred!').
2. I want to hide/show some content depending on user role (like display admin dropdown only for admins).

Where should I store user login/name and role on client side (that implemented via html/js/jquery and etc.)? Is it safe to store it like cookies? Or, maybe, I should make some additional request on server like 'who am i' endpoint? What about local storage? And is it safe to store user login and role (without password) in cookies/other?

Answer (score 0):

In client side, you can use PHP sessions. It's safe and simple!

When the user sign in, start a session and set session variables:`session_start(); $_SESSION['username'] = "something";`

If you want to access session variables on another pages, you have to do this: `session_start(); echo $_SESSION['username'];`.

More information here: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Good luck ;)

Comment: Take care not to confuse client side with server side code execution. PHP runs on the server.

Comment: Yes, but you can access it in client side. I think that it solves the problem

Comment: No. You can't access the PHP session data on the client side. Only the session id is stored in a client side cookie. You can access it only on the server side. To get the data to the client you will have to take further steps (*on the server side*) and put it into the http response (like you do it with `echo`). That is not the same thing.